# Se me descoloca la tabla html

Tags: html

***Tengo este código html:***

```
<h1>Edit Taking</h1>
<table class="table table-dark">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Película</th>
            <th>País</th>
            <th>Año</th>
            <th>Distribuidora</th>
            <th>Recaudación</th>
            <th>Ranking</th>
            <th>Espectadores</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ taking.film }}</td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="taking.country"/>
            <td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    class="form-control" 
                    ng-model="taking.year"
                />
            <td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    class="form-control" 
                    ng-model="taking.distributor"
                />
            <td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    class="form-control" 
                    ng-model="taking.money"
                />
            <td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    class="form-control" 
                    ng-model="taking.rank"
                />
            <td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    class="form-control" 
                    ng-model="taking.spectator"
                />
            <td>

                <button 
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    ng-click="putdataform(taking.film)";
                >Update</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Y me sale descuadrado tanto filas como columnas , no sé a que se debe. Dejo un ejemplo de como sale ahora mismo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tu CSS?

Comment: No tengo CSS , todo va por Bootstrap y AngularJS

Comment: No cierras tus `td`. Los abres y utilizas otra etiqueta para abrir en vez de cerrarlos, deberían ser `</td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que no cierras las etiquetas, revisalas, puede ser ese tu error:

```
<h1>Edit Taking</h1>
<table class="table table-dark">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Película</th>
            <th>País</th>
            <th>Año</th>
            <th>Distribuidora</th>
            <th>Recaudación</th>
            <th>Ranking</th>
            <th>Espectadores</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ taking.film }}</td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="taking.country"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    class="form-control" 
                    ng-model="taking.year"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    class="form-control" 
                    ng-model="taking.distributor"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    class="form-control" 
                    ng-model="taking.money"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    class="form-control" 
                    ng-model="taking.rank"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input 
                    class="form-control" 
                    ng-model="taking.spectator"
                />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button 
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    ng-click="putdataform(taking.film)";
                >Update</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Vaya que tontería , ni me he dado cuenta. Gracias

Answer (score 2):

no estas cerrando las etiquetas `<td></td>` correctamente en el `<tbody>`

por ejemplo

```html
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ taking.film }}</td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="taking.country"/>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input 
                class="form-control" 
                ng-model="taking.year"
            />
        </td>
```